# VBScript MySql connection

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I've got a problem connecting my vbscript to a mySql database. I get no error messages. After running my program the database doesn't change anything.

```
Dim dbconn, connect

connect = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.6.20 Driver};Server=localhost;PORT=3306;Database=test;User=root;"

Set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )

dbconn.Open connect

dbconn.Execute = "DELETE FROM test_2"
dbconn.Close
```

I checked the driver, it's okay, i've got sql connector.
Also i can modify this database from c#.

So no error messages... Any idea?

Comment: `dbconn.Execute` is a method, not a property: try removing the `=`, ie `dbconn.Execute "DELETE FROM test_2"`